# NetBeans J2ME FileBrowser browse only folder?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, midlet, file-browser

I'm using NetBeans to build a folder browser application. In application flow, i place a file browser control to browse files and folders.

My problem: The file browser control always list both folders and files.

My question: How can i set the file browser control to list only folders?

Answer (score 1):

When you are looking for new list of files&folders to browse you can filter and only add folders:

```
while (enum1.hasMoreElements()) {
                    current = (String) enum1.nextElement();
                    if (current.endsWith("\") || current.endsWith("/")) {
                        folders.addElement(current);
                    }


         }
 }
```